# Drupal6: Load a field, like one would load a node?

Tags: validation, drupal, forms

Is there a `field_load()` function equivalent to `node_load()`? I want to get information about the type of a field and other validation constraints without going to the database myself.

Better yet, is there any function that will validate it for me, like `is_valid_for_field(field_name, input)`, that would take a field name and a potential input and return a boolean indicating whether or not the potential input is valid (within min/max, etc) for the specified field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [content_fields()](http://api.zzolo.org/api/function/content_fields/drupal-6) function, which will get you the meta data for a field. In terms of validation, IIRC, you can call [content_field()](http://api.zzolo.org/api/function/content_field/drupal-6) with the operation set to validate, and the relevant data. However, by calling node_save with your completed node, the cck module will take care of all the relevant validation hooks for the entire node structure, so you may be better off taking that route.

Comment: Including validating taxonomy? (referenced terms really do exist, and they are allowed to be applied to that node type, etc)